# Remove specific (known) extension from filename if it's there

Tags: grep, regular-expression, filenames, string

I'm not even sure whether `grep` is meant to be used for regex in one-line data. Googling led me to this lookahead expression that, along with `grep`, matches any `.ext` file and returns bare name:

```
XX@XX:/$ echo name.ext | grep -oP [^\.]+(?=.ext)
name
```

That's nice, but now I prompt user for saving a file and I'm not sure whether he'll type the name with the extension or not. I tried making the lookahead conditional, ensuring all names are matched, but that returns something I don't understand:

```
XX@XX:/$ echo name.ext | grep -oP "[^\.]+(?=.ext)?"
name
ext
```

It works if I ommit the extension though:

```
XX@XX:/$ echo name | grep -oP "[^\.]+(?=.ext)?"
name
```

So is this a grep problem or regex problem? Maybe I need to somehow make the lookahead non capturing?

Comment: Just in case you would like to solve the problem a different way, consider something like: `basename name.ext .ext` -> "name"; `basename name.ext4 .ext` -> "name.ext4"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use POSIX shell substitution to remove the `.ext`:

```
file='name.ext'
printf '%s\n' "${file%.ext}"
```

To assign the extention free string to a new variable, do

```
noext="${file%.ext}"
```

Comment: Can I somehow also use this expression in direct assignment (eg. without <code>\`</code> character).

Comment: I meant backtick, that's why I tried `<code>` to escape it. And no, there's no backtick in your code, but if I were to assign result to variable, I'd do this: `var=\`printf '%s' "${file%.ext}"\``

Answer (score 0):

Using your approach (there are better solutions):

```
echo name | grep -oP '^[^.]+(?=(\.ext)?$)'
```

Comment: If there are better solutions, please post them! I don't insist on grep, it's just the only thing I got working so far.